# Multiplying $P(x) = (x-1)(x-2) \dots (x-50)$ and $Q(x)=(x+1)(x+2) \cdots(x+50)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

> Let $P(x) = (x-1)(x-2) \dots (x-50)$ and $Q(x)=(x+1)(x+2) \cdots(x+50).$
>
> If $P(x)Q(x) = a_{100}x^{100} + a_{99}x^{99} + \dots + a_{1}x^{1} + a_0$, compute $a_{100} - a_{99} - a_{98} - a_{97}.$

I've been quite stuck with this one. If I multiply and group the polynomials with the similar terms e.g $(x-1)$ and $(x+1) ...$ I would get

$P(x)Q(x)= (x^2-1)(x^2-2^2) \dots(x^2-50^2)$ right? From here on if I would keep multiplying the terms wouldn't I end up with $50$ times the term $x^2$ as the initial term, hence $a_{100} = 1$ since it wouldn't have any coefficient? For the other terms I don't have a clue how to find them so any hints would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried [Vieta's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)?

Comment: How would Vieta's help here?

Comment: Have you tried? You'd see that $a_{99}=0$ almost immediately ...

Comment: I cannot see clearly how to apply this since the degree of the product of the polynomials is so big?

Comment: The roots of $P(x)\cdot Q(x)$ are $-50,-49,...,-2,-1,1,2,...,49,50$. The sum of the roots is zero, that is $a_{99}$.

Comment: @rtybase: I think it's even more helpful to apply this principle to the OP's product form, as a function of $x^2$.

Comment: @BrianTung or that way indeed ... $P(x)\cdot Q(x)= T(x^2)$.

Comment: Just see how many ways you can get $x^100$, 1 way, $x^99$ and others can be calculated the same way and we get the number of coefficients

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clearly $a_{99}=a_{97}=0$, since only even degree terms appear. As you've noticed, $a_{100}=1$; so really we just need to find $a_{98}$. But this is just negative $1$ times the sum of squares up to $50$, i.e. $-\sum_{k=1}^{50} k^2 =- \frac{50\cdot 51\cdot 101}{6}=-42925$. So the answer is $42926$.

Edit: it seems I was a bit sparse with my explanation. Claim: the coefficient of $x^{2n-2}$ in $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x^2-i^2)$ is $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$. The claim is immediate when $n=1$ or $n=2$:
$$
(n=1)\qquad \prod_{i=1}^{1}(x^2-i^2)= x^2-1;\, 1 = \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3}{6}
$$
$$
(n=2)\qquad \prod_{i=1}^{2}(x^2-i^2)= x^4-5x^2+1;\, 5 = \frac{2\cdot 3 \cdot 5}{6}
$$Suppose the result is true for some $k$. Then
$$
\prod_{i=1}^{k+1 }(x^2-i^2) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{k }(x^2-i^2)\right)\cdot(x^2-(k+1)^2)
$$
$$
 = \left(x^{2k}-\sum_{i=1}^{k}i^2 \cdot x^{2k-2} +\cdots\right)\cdot(x^2-(k+1)^2)
$$
$$
 = \left(x^{2k+2}-((k+1)^2+\sum_{i=1}^{k}i^2) \cdot x^{2k} +\cdots\right),
$$as was to be shown.

Comment: By even terms you mean what exactly? Isn't the third term in both $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ already odd $(x-3)$ and $(x+3)$?

Comment: @Daniel: Odd terms referring to coefficients of odd powers of $x$; there aren't any because the product only involves $x^2$ terms (and constants).

Comment: Ah I see. However, how does this imply that $a_{99} = a_{97} = 0$? Since $99$ and $97$ are odd?

Comment: @Sil No, you're right.  The approach in this answer is correct, but the computation was incorrect.  The sum of squares is $42925$, leading to the value $1-(-42925) = 42926$.  Integrand's sum went to $100^2$ instead of $50^2$.

Comment: The formula is also correct: If you evaluate $\frac{50\cdot51\cdot101}{6}$, you do indeed get $42925$.

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that's right.  $a_{99}$ would be the coefficient of $x^{99}$; since that power doesn't appear in the polynomial's expansion, that coefficient must be $a_{99} = 0$.

Comment: Alright thanks for taking the time! Now I just got to figure out the logic Integrand applied to find $a_{98}.$ I don't quite follow how $-1$ times the sum of squares up to $100$ leads there.

Comment: @Daniel: If you have $f(x) = (x+a_1)(x+a_2)(x+a_3)\cdots(x+a_n)$, the coefficient of $x^n$ is of course just $1$, but what is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$?  We can determine this by looking at how we get $x^{n-1}$ from this product: We must have $n-1$ factors of $x$, and any of the $a_i$ as the $n$th and final factor.  There are $n$ ways to do this, so we have $(a_1+a_2+a_3+\cdots+a_n)x^{n-1}$.

Comment: As an example: If you have $(x+1)(x-2)(x+4)$, then the $x^2$ term is $1 \times x \times x$ plus $x \times (-2) \times x$ plus $x \times x \times 4$, which equals $(1-2+4)x^2 = 3x^2$.  Note how we treated the $x-2$ term as $x+(-2)$.  The only variation here is that instead of $x$, we have $x^2$.